# How to retrieve records where two conditions occur more than 1 time

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm not sure I phrased the title question correctly.   What I'm trying to do is find records where the parameter codes 94 and 95 occur together in a single sample_id.   What I've got so far is the query below, but it returns records where EITHER 94 or 95 occur more than once per sample_id.

```
SELECT
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.sample_id,
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.param_name
FROM
    wq.wq_site_sample_result
WHERE
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.pcode IN (
        94,
        95
    )
GROUP BY
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.sample_id,
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.param_name
HAVING COUNT(SAMPLE_ID) >1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close:

```
SELECT ssr.sample_id
FROM wq.wq_site_sample_result ssr
WHERE ssr.pcode IN (94, 95)
GROUP BY ssr.sample_id
HAVING count(distinct ssr.pcode) = 2;
```

Note the use of table aliases to simplify the query code.  Your question mentions samples, so that is the only thing being selected and aggregated on.  The `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is in case the data can have duplicates.  If not, then `COUNT(*)` is fine.

It is unclear what `ssr.param_name` is doing.  It *might* be appropriate in the `HAVING` clause.  On the other hand, if there can be multiple values, then `LISTAGG()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked.  I actually neglected to ask another question:  sample_ids that contain more than 1 value for  95 but ALSO contain 94.    I'm working on it and post when I try.

Comment: @Mr.Geologist . . . Feel free to ask a new question with appropriate sample data and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the wq.wq_site_sample_result.pcode column with a distinct
like below - `count(distinct wq.wq_site_sample_result.pcode)`

```
SELECT
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.sample_id,
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.param_name
FROM
    wq.wq_site_sample_result
WHERE
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.pcode IN (
        94,
        95
    )
GROUP BY
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.sample_id,
    wq.wq_site_sample_result.param_name
HAVING COUNT(distinct wq.wq_site_sample_result.pcode) >1;
```

Comment: thank you for the input but this query returns zero results.  I know results exist though.